# Combining two functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I attempted to combine two functions in the code below. All seems to be working except I cannot get the variable `currentImage.metaData.something` to work in the second function. I appreciate your advice.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.photoswipe-2.1.5.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(window, PhotoSwipe){

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

            var
                options =  {

                    getImageMetaData: function(el){
                        return {
                            href: el.getAttribute('href'),
                            something: el.getAttribute('data-something'),
                            anotherThing: el.getAttribute('data-another-thing')
                        }
                    }

                },
                instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), options );


            instance.addEventHandler(PhotoSwipe.EventTypes.onDisplayImage, function(e){

                var currentImage = instance.getCurrentImage();
                console.log(currentImage.metaData.something);
                console.log(currentImage.metaData.anotherThing);

            });


        }, false);


    }(window, window.Code.Util, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));


    (function(window, Util, PhotoSwipe){



        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

            var
                sayHiEl,
                sayHiClickHandler = function(e){
                    alert('yo!!!');
                }
                options = {

                    getToolbar: function(){
                        return '<div class="ps-toolbar-close" style="padding-top: 12px;">Close</div><div class="ps-toolbar-play" style="padding-top: 12px;">Play</div><div class="ps-toolbar-previous" style="padding-top: 12px;">Previous</div><div class="ps-toolbar-next" style="padding-top: 12px;">Next</div><div class="say-hi" style="padding-top: 12px;">Say Hi!</div>';
                        // NB. Calling PhotoSwipe.Toolbar.getToolbar() wil return the default toolbar HTML
                    }

                },
                instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), options );

                // onShow - store a reference to our "say hi" button
                instance.addEventHandler(PhotoSwipe.EventTypes.onShow, function(e){
                    sayHiEl = window.document.querySelectorAll('.say-hi')[0];
                });

                // onToolbarTap - listen out for when the toolbar is tapped
                instance.addEventHandler(PhotoSwipe.EventTypes.onToolbarTap, function(e){
                    if (e.toolbarAction === PhotoSwipe.Toolbar.ToolbarAction.none){
                        if (e.tapTarget === sayHiEl || Util.DOM.isChildOf(e.tapTarget, sayHiEl)){
                            alert(currentImage.metaData.anotherThing);
                        }
                    }
                });

                // onBeforeHide - clean up
                instance.addEventHandler(PhotoSwipe.EventTypes.onBeforeHide, function(e){
                    sayHiEl = null;
                });


        }, false);


    }(window, window.Code.Util, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
```

Comment: Are you aware of the fact you're passing `window.Code.Util` as `PhotoSwipe` and not using `window.Code.PhotoSwipe` (the third argument) in the first function?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Does it output any specific error messages? Could you remove the code to reduce it to the specific problem you're having? Could you [make a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) where we could try this out?

Comment: Ok figured it out with JS fiddle. WIll post link soon

Comment: @Sii :OK here is the JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/uF3ZU/ . Basically, when you click on an image in the gallery. you see the say hi button lower right corner. I want that alert to display either or both of the meta values: data-something" data-another-thing using the function.

Comment: Well, one problem is what @jmar777 answered, but it seems that the metaData property of currentImage doesn't contain anything when in the toolbar button event handler. Also, the getImageMetadata callback never gets called. Possibly because in the the first onload handler, PhotoSwipe.attach doesn't exist. Etc and so forth, the problem isn't at all localised to where it manifests. I recommend you pore through the code with a Javascript console open, and sprinkling `console.log()` around it liberally to verify that everything you're assuming works actually does.

Comment: Yes I thought so. It looks a little messed up. Thank you for looking!! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the `currentImage` variable within the first function.  Variables created with the `var` keyword are function-scoped, meaning that it isn't visible outside of the function (and hence not visible in your second function, in this case).

I would probably suggest some more general code reorganization, but an easy fix would be to declare the variable above both of your functions, making it visible to both.

Comment: Or just retrieve it with `instance.getCurrentImage()` again.  Although that just out pops out an alert saying "undefined", so I'd say a general cleanup is in order.